# How to alter data handling to be less repeated?

Tags: swift, sqlite

In Swift I'm creating an app with SQLite. I have an insert function for tables `USER_TASKS`, `USER_APPTS` and `USER_FINANCES`. All function do the same thing so I ideally have one insert/retrieve/delete even for varying data types, varying number of columns, etc. The insert string and data binding seem like each data type needs its own insert function.

Example insert function for `FOOD`:

```
    let insertStatementString = "INSERT INTO USER_FOODS (NAME_OF_FOOD, TYPE_OF_FOOD, AMOUNT_OF_FOOD) values (?, ?, ?);"

    var insertStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertStatementString, -1, &insertStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK
    {
        sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 1, (Food.nameOfFood as NSString).utf8String, -1, nil)
        sqlite3_bind_int(insertStatement, 2, Int32(Food.typeOfFood))
        sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 3, (Food.amountOfFood as NSString).utf8String, -1, nil)

        if sqlite3_step(insertStatement) == SQLITE_DONE
        {
            print("Successfully inserted row.")
        }
        else
        {
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
            print("error finalizing prepared insert statement: \(errmsg)")
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(insertStatement)
    sqlite3_close(db)
}
```

I'm not sure how to start.

Comment: It looks like you're looking for an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), perhaps like Vapour's [Fluent](https://docs.vapor.codes/fluent/overview/)

Comment: For a pretty simple approach that is likely the most approachable for building your own, see https://github.com/ryanfowler/SwiftData.  For a larger system that you would likely just drop in place, but is very close to SQLite, see https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift. For a much fancier system, see https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift  (Nish's suggestion of macros are also a very interesting approach that may work for you, but are new enough that there aren't a lot of examples to point to.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a new swift feature called **Macros** (provided with swift 5.9), that will work for you.

Macros can read the **name of the type** as well as each **name and type of each stored variable** in the type.

These requirements should suffice for you to be able to generate the SQLStatement boilerplate code for your model object

One of the developers from the swift core team has provided a few examples of how to use this feature in this github repo which would come in handy

https://github.com/DougGregor/swift-macro-examples

In the context of the question you asked, you might be able to add an annotation to a struct so it looks something like what's shown below

```
@SQLStatementGenerator
struct UserFoods {
    let nameOfFood: String
    let typeOfFood: Int
    let amountOfFood: String
}
```

and have the Macro exapand to add `func insertIntoDB(dbLocation: String)`

because the function generated is not static you can read the values for the various properties to use proper values in your generated statement

dbLocation will come in handy to create the Opaque Pointer to database handle

Additional References to understand the feature a bit more:

1. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10166/
2. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10167/

If you do not wish to use swift beta feature, I would recommend using boilerplate generators like sourcery to do the same. You can find sourcery examples at the link below

https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery